# unable to resolve method in class

Tags: javascript, gwt, openlayers, jsni

1.is it possible to call the native method in the gwt into the other native method ?

this is the method i am calling from the VectorSource.java into Map.java 
https://github.com/VOL3/v-ol3/blob/master/gwt-ol3/src/main/java/org/vaadin/gwtol3/client/source/VectorSource.java

```
 public final native JsArray<Feature> getFeatures()/*-{
        return this.getFeatures();
    }-*/;
```

and i created a native method in  Map.java class and getting the Features and i want to return these feature values to  ***addOnPostRenderListener*** method  below are the  changes in the Map.java class

```
    public native final Feature getFeatures(VectorSource sourceFeature)/*-{
    var features=sourceFeature.@org.vaadin.gwtol3.client.source.VectorSource::getFeatures();
    return features;
    }-*/;


    public native final void addOnPostRenderListener(OnPostRenderListener listener)/*-{


       if(!this.__registered){
       var that=this;

       that.once('postrender',function(){
        var feature=that.@org.vaadin.gwtol3.client.Map::getFeatures(vectorSource);
        if(feature!=null){
        var coordinate=feature.getGeometry().getCoordinate();
        if(coordinates!=null){
        var MapEvent={Pixel:that.getPixelFromCoordinate(that.__transformInputCoordinate(coordinates))};
        that.__notifyPostRenderListeners(MapEvent);
        }
        }})
        this.__postRenderListeners.push(listener);
        }
    }-*/;
```

the remaining code remains the same as shown in the below link 
https://github.com/VOL3/v-ol3/blob/master/gwt-ol3/src/main/java/org/vaadin/gwtol3/client/Map.java

at the below code  i am getting the error,as ***Expected a valid parameter type signature in JSNI method reference*** these lines of code  is in the **addOnPostRenderListener** method

```
 var feature=that.@org.vaadin.gwtol3.client.Map::getFeatures(vectorSource);
```

my target is to call the method getFeatures() from VectorSource.java class  into the Map.java class  and send the values to the other native method which is   addOnPostRenderListener method.

**Interface**

```
public interface OnPostRenderListener {

    public void onRender(MapEvent posEvent);
}
```

**MapEvent**

```
public class MapEvent extends JavaScriptObject {


    protected MapEvent() {

    }


     public static final native Feature create()/*-{
     return new $wnd.ol.Feature();
      }-*/;


     public native final Geometry getGeometry()-{
        return this.getGeometry();
       }-;*/


    public native final Geometry getGeometry()/*-{
        return this.geometry;
    }-*/;

    public native final Coordinate getCoordinate()/*-{
    return this.coordinate;
     }-*/;


   public native final Pixel getPixel()/*-{
    return this.Pixel;
    }-*/;

   //written code not used 
   public native final Map getPixelFromCoordinate(Coordinate coord)/*-{
     return this.getPixelFromCoordinate(coord);
    }-*/;
}
```

Comment: which version of gwt are you using?

Comment: @Halko 2.8.0 version but you can not see this in the Api of 2.8.0 because these are the extended methods written by me to get the pixelvalues of the polygon on the map using gwt-ol3 API

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your `VectorSource sourceFeature` parameter too. You are missing it in `that.@org.vaadin.gwtol3.client.Map::getFeatures(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/Source;);`.

One way to do this, would be add it to your

`addOnPostRenderListener(OnPostRenderListener listener)`

e.g. `addOnPostRenderListener(OnPostRenderListener listener, VectorSource vectorSource)`

and then to access it like this:

```
var feature=that.@org.vaadin.gwtol3.client.Map::getFeatures(vectorSource);
```

Although I would recommend to completely **drop JSNI** and use the much better **JsInterop**. There is an OL-implementation using JsInterop too. Take a look **[here](https://github.com/TDesjardins/gwt-ol3)**

Comment: but i dont want to give two arguements because this totally change the design of v-ol3 API  when i  called this  addOnPostRenderListener(OnPostRenderListener listener) ; , is there any chance with only one arguement ?

Comment: updated my answer - don't know if that would be an option for you

Comment: Expected a valid parameter type signature in JSNI method reference ,,i am getting tstill this error

Comment: did you fix this line too? `this.__postRenderListeners.push(OnPostRenderListener);` should be `this.__postRenderListeners.push(listener);`

Comment: i changed my code according to the above lines  you mentioned, but still i am facing the issue at  var feature=that.@org.vaadin.gwtol3.client.Map::getFeatures(vectorSource);  the error is ::::: Expected a valid parameter type signature in JSNI method reference

Comment: then update your code in the question to match your current code please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176734/discussion-between-ramanamuttana-and-halko-karr-sajtarevic).